# How to solve starvation with notify and notifyall?

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

How to solve starvation with `notify` and `notifyall`?

If we have 4 threads, waiting to acquire a lock on same obj,and the current thread calls `notify()`

The JVM will select any one thread. Is it possible that thread which called `notify()`, can again be picked by JVM, as after calling `notify()`, it would be also in waiting thread list.

This might lead to starvation problem if one of the thread is invoked more number of times than others, unless there is some mechanism where longest waiting thread is picked up first.

I am assuming here that all threads are of same priority. If thread priorities are different, I think highest priority thread will be picked up when `notify()`

Also, same issues would crop up with `notifyall()` I think where we don't know which thread  will be picked.

Answer (score 5):

If you care which thread gets notified, you are doing something wrong. Whatever the notification requires to be done, any thread that is waiting for a notification *must* be able to do it. If this logic doesn't apply to your use case, then `notify` is not appropriate for your use case.

Concern about thread fairness generally indicates poorly-designed code. It's your job to make sure your code only does work you actually want it to do and, if necessary, does the most important work first. You shouldn't be expecting the scheduler to somehow do this. The scheduler's job is to get as much work done as possible, enforcing priorities and fairness between processes. The programmer's job is to write code that does the right work.

Comment: A application that relies on fairness for correctness is poorly designed.  But an application could also rely on fairness to (on average) minimize the execution time.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the threads are randomly picked from the `notify()` function or `notifiAll()` function. 
What you can do is you can use the `ReetrantLock` with Fair policy. Fair policy avoid thread starvation.

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Comment: ReentrantLock has [newCondition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition%28%29) to allow you to get wait/notify semantics with a fair lock. This condition is fair, `notify` wakes threads in FIFO order.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ask what the virtual machine is actually doing. I'm going to look at OpenJDK. After some digging (source code available [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/)) we find that the wait method is implemented by this bit of C++.

```
JVM_ENTRY(void, JVM_MonitorWait(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle, jlong ms))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_MonitorWait");
  Handle obj(THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(handle));
  assert(obj->is_instance() || obj->is_array(), "JVM_MonitorWait must apply to an object");
  JavaThreadInObjectWaitState jtiows(thread, ms != 0);
  if (JvmtiExport::should_post_monitor_wait()) {
    JvmtiExport::post_monitor_wait((JavaThread *)THREAD, (oop)obj(), ms);
  }
  ObjectSynchronizer::wait(obj, ms, CHECK);
JVM_END
```

Which we follow down to the following defined for `ObjectSynchronizer`

```
void ObjectSynchronizer::waitUninterruptibly (Handle obj, jlong millis, TRAPS) {
  if (UseBiasedLocking) {
    BiasedLocking::revoke_and_rebias(obj, false, THREAD);
    assert(!obj->mark()->has_bias_pattern(), "biases should be revoked by now");
  }
  if (millis < 0) {
    TEVENT (wait - throw IAX) ;
    THROW_MSG(vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalArgumentException(), "timeout value is negative");
  }
  ObjectSynchronizer::inflate(THREAD, obj()) -> wait(millis, false, THREAD) ;
}
```

And then to the `ObjectMonitor` returned by `inflate` where we find this commend

```
   // Enter the waiting queue, which is a circular doubly linked list in this case
   // but it could be a priority queue or any data structure.
```

and some `ObjectWaiter` code that implements aforementioned doubly linked list.

So what have I learnt? Well, firstly that the Hotspot code isn't actually that difficult to navigate. But more relevant to your question - in (this implementation of the JVM) the wait set is implemented as a queue... so threads are given the lock on a first in first out basis. Which means that if any other threads are waiting on the lock they will get it first.

Of course we should never use that information... as the comment above says the wait list can be implemented however the JVM people want to implement it. The JLS gives no indication of the order in which threads should be notified. But I've learnt something if nobody else has.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to solve with wait/notify(All) but you can look at ReentrantLock/Condition with fairness set to true. [ReentrantLock javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29). It shouldn't matter which of your threads gets the work though.

Answer (score 0):

No, a thread that calls `Object.notify` must own the lock on the object and notifies threads that previously relinqueshed their locks on that object with a call to `Object.wait` - the notifying thread can't simultaniously notify and wait.

From the [`Object.notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) JavaDoc:

*The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object*