# Thread Scheduling-How thread acquires the lock after notify called

Tags: java, multithreading

I have doubt on how the thread acquires the lock with following scenario,

There are 3 Threads.

*Thread-1 acquires lock and call wait method on the object1

*Thread-2 acquires lock and call wait method on the object1

*Thread-3 acquires lock and call notify method on the object1

Now how the JVM wakes up the thread. Thread-1 acquires the lock on the monitor object or Thread-2 acquires the lock? Please explain the reason in detail.

Assume all the thread has same priority.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hi the documentation for the method notify in the [javadocs for the jdk 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) states:

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If
>   any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be
>   awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the
>   implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one
>   of the wait methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If JVM always chooses to wake up Thread-1 and Thread-2 is not given chance,what happens here? I know reentrant lock to do fairness lock.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063426/how-to-solve-starvation-with-notify-and-notifyall for a detailed response. Short one: use ReentrantLock instead of relying on wait/notify

Comment: @Lathy The JVM doesn't choose, it leaves it to the OS to implement this which is also why it is far more efficient than a fair lock which is implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Notification order is impossible to predict in advance. Any of the two threads - Thread-1 or Thread-2 can get the lock and you should program as per that model, not according to any fixed order notification or lock acquisition.